# Scope variable and ng-include in Angular are not harmonizing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a file dropzone to get data content of a file.
If I set the `$scope.importData` to null, it is not possible to assign data inside the drop handler anymore.

```
$scope.handleDrop = function(evt) {
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
      var files = evt.dataTransfer ? evt.dataTransfer.files : evt.target.files,
          file = files[0],
          reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
          var content = evt.target.result;
          if('' !== content) {
              $scope.importData = content; //will work as long you do not set $scope.importData to null
              $scope.$apply();
          }
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
};
```

I figured out the problem might be the ng-include. If I do it without the include, it will work.

Please try the Plunker...

http://plnkr.co/edit/BFOquRMLOqpL3arv1rtI?p=preview

Comment: Be sure you go through the Angular docs first before continuing with your project. DOM and event management is supposed to be handled from inside the directives, and not from the controllers.

Comment: @Stewie Okay, I updated the code and added directives for the events. But the problem is the same

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I improved the question. Hope this is okay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ngInclude creates a new scope that prototypically inherits from its parent scope, in your plunker example the parent scope being the scope of your `pageCtrl`. The problem with your example is that inside `$scope.addSetReImport` you are setting `var $scope = this;` and in that context `this` refers to ngInclude's scope and not your `pageCtrl` scope, so `$scope.importData = null;` effectively overrides the prototype `importData` variable with a property on ngInclude's scope. The following screenshot from Chrome's console illustrates this override, this is from ngInclude's $scope:

[image]

So you end up with two `importData` variables, one sitting on your ngInclude's scope and used inside your modal template, which is pointing to null, and a second one that sits on your `pageCtrl` scope that is used during the `handleDrop` function. Since `handleDrop` will update the `importData` on the `pageCtrl` scope, it will not reflect on the property set on the ngInclude scope that your template is using.

To get your example working, just remove the `var $scope = this;` from your `addSetReImport` function, this ensures you are referencing the scope of your `pageCtrl`. Here is a cloned plunker with a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/LvYGKqLlL9Pxq0X5slyM?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not expect that it is so easy.